# Dynamic Expressions in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Are we able to do Dynamic Expressions in Mapreduce?

Say if I am having a `csv` file which has 2 columns.
The user is giving an expresion

```
col1  + col2 = col3
```

And when again the user wants `col1 - col2 = col4`.

Are we able to do this?

How to do that?
Should we do all those operations in 1 Mapreduce Program or whether we need to create MapReduce program for each  expressions? (`dynamic change of expressions from user`)

Comment: Sounds like Pig or Hive are better fits for your use case than bare metal map reduce.

Comment: Thank you for the reply judge - What is the shortcome of my case in implementing it in mapreduce?

Answer (score 1):

As Judge Mental said in the comment you should take a look at [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) or [Pig](https://pig.apache.org/).

Using Hive you can launch MapReduce jobs with SQL queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col1 + col2 AS col3, col1 - col2 AS col4
  FROM table
```

Comment: So Hive or Pg is the best. Are we not able to  do that in MapReduce.What is the limitation of MapReduce in the same Nigel?

Comment: Well, with raw MapReduce you'll need to parse user input (col1 + col2 etc). Basically you'll reinvent Hive/Pig. With Hive/Pig you'll still be using MapReduce but Hive/Pig will do the parsing job for you.

Comment: So Nigel if we are doing in Hive/pig..what will be the performance(fastness). Is it same as that of mapreduce?

Comment: Can't tell anything about Pig (I've never used it) but Hive runs about 10% slower than raw MapReduce on my data. You should compare Hive/Pig/MapReduce performance on your data. One of the main advantages of Hive is the development speed. The simplest MapReduce job requires 40 lines of Java. The simples Hive query is 1 line.